# Sending json posts from WordPress to an android app

Tags: android, json, wordpress

Hope someone can help. I am using an app that sends HTTP POST requests.I have a Wordpress site and i want to host a list numberplates that we are going to call denied plates

the following is from the app developer:

**Request
The android device sends a HTTP POST message to the given url + /api/bwlist path. The app
generates a regular HTTP multipart message with the following fields:

• nationality: The plate’s nationality
• plate: the plate text

This is an HTML that generates the same message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
 <form action="http://ip:port/api/bwlist" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Plate</label>
 <input type="text" name="plate" value="ARH001"><br>
 <label>Nat</label>
 <input type="text" name="nationality" value="HUN"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>

Result
For such a request, the server responds with a JSON text. Currently it has only one field: “type”.
The value can be “deny”, “allow” or “none” (lowercase). An example of such a result is the
following:
{
“type”:”deny”
}**
```

can someone please explain in simple terms how i can create an api that sends a response if the plate sent in the HTTP POST is in a denied list its not someting ive ever dne before but im good with wordpress to a limited level. TIA

Comment: where is the plae data being stored currently? is it a custom database? or is it wordpress posts?

Comment: Currently the data is stored on Google sheets and on a html file. I am in the process of setting up sn integration between Google sheets and mysql to get the data into my database

Comment: that would depend as you need to compare the data inputted by the POST request.

Comment: I am happy to store it anywhere. Correct, here is a scenario: we have a list of vehicles that are denied access to a certain area. every time a car is scanned with the app it sends a HTTP POST with the Vehicle country code, in our case GBR for Great Britain and the registration plate.

Comment: i think from what i understand if the vehicle data sent in the HTTP POST matches in the Database on my server it responds with deny. and if its not it does not respond. would that be correct? im new to this so would like to learn. the data can be stored any where required.

Answer (score 0):

So we'll start with the database part. you'll need to set up a database table to store the data. feel free to alter the MYSQL data types

so we're using wordpress [`dbDelta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/dbdelta/) function and a table that stores all the vehicle info as well as a status (feel free to alter table columns)

```
function vehicles_database_functions(){
    global $wpdb;
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    
    $table_name_vehicles = $wpdb->prefix . 'vehicles';
    $table_name_vehicle_status = $wpdb->prefix . 'vehicle_status';
    
    $vehicles_sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name_vehicles . " (
        id int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        numberplate_country_code varchar(3) NOT NULL,
        numberplate varchar(10) NOT NULL,
        type char(5) NOT NULL,
        date_created timestamp NOT NULL,
        date_modified timestamp NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
    
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($vehicles_sql);
    
}

vehicles_database_functions();
```

now that we have the database set up you can fill it with vehicle content.

next you'll want to handle the HTTP request:

so make a new file in your theme root called `plate_callback.php`

inside that file you'll handle all the HTTP request: (make sure you set up some sort of verification to know whos posting to your website is who it says it is.

```
$country_code = isset( $_POST['country_code'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['country_code'] ) : '';
$numberplate = isset( $_POST['numberplate'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['numberplate'] ) : '';
$type = isset( $_POST['type'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['type'] ) : '';

if( $country_code && $numberplate && $type ){
    global $wpdb;
    
    $table_name_vehicles = $wpdb->prefix . 'vehicles';
    
    $denied_vehicle = $wpdb->get_row( 
        $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $table_name_vehicles WHERE numberplate_country_code=%s AND numberplate=%s AND denied_entry=%s", array( $country_code, $numberplate, $type ) ), ARRAY_A
    );
    
    if( $denied_vehicle ){
        
        $vehicle_status = array('type' => $denied_vehicle['type']);
        echo json_encode($vehicle_status);
        
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
    
}
else{
    wp_die('Error Message');
}
```

This should get you started off in the right direction